# How to make applications run only on one type of android device?

Tags: android, device, samsung-mobile

Today, i have a question and need to help.
Is there a way to make an android application run only on some type of device ? (Like it run only in Samsung or Sony device..)
And how to do it?

Thanks for help !

Comment: Why would you impose such a restriction?

Comment: @MattBall: Like some applications has made exclusive for some manufacturers

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you  can do this with the help of following code....

```
public String getDeviceName() {
  String manufacturer = Build.MANUFACTURER;
  String model = Build.MODEL;
  if (model.startsWith(manufacturer)) {
    return capitalize(model);
  } else {
    return capitalize(manufacturer) + " " + model;
  }
}
```

and then :

```
 if (

    manufactures == "Samsung" || "samsung")
   {

    Log.d ("device","This device manufactured from samsung");
}

    else {

    Log.d ("device","This device not manufactured from samsung Sorry!!!");
}
```

Comment: Well you might as well make the conditional `if ("samsung".equalsIgnoreCase(manufacturer)){` to keep it proper Java like the rest of the code.

Comment: Just did it ! 
Thankyou !